# collapsing divs that will show the information

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page in C#.Net (*.aspx) where I am displaying the report in the form of gridview and showing different counts that is a number and clicking on it on another page it displays the person's information..

eg.

```
Total Number of People Enrolled             8
Total Number of People Enrolled as Email    5
```

On clicking on "8" or "5" will display all "8" or "5" persons on the new page..

Now what I want is instead of clicking on the value and going to another page, we're going to have collapsing divs that will show the information and expand when you click on the value.

So How can I achieve that..?

example:

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an accordion control. There are plenty of examples on the net and there are plenty of them free to download and use. We used it in our department not long ago. This means that you don't have to write all that jquery and CSS to achieve the desired result.

This is what we used http://jqueryui.com/ and there's heaps of documentation and help on Google. But seriously, if you do want something as cool as this, there will have to be some effort from you and its not a huge learning curve, its very very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Which part are you struggling with? Conceptually you would hide the child records by default, and toggle them when the parent is clicked.

[A trivial example looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/5uGTY/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use HoverMenuExtender of Ajax Control ToolKit.

go to the following link for demo you'll get your answer better:[Ajax Control ToolKit Samples](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx)

Comment: This will not work for me because I need some processing after redirection..so is there something like the page will open in a panel or an iframe..

Comment: why not, there is a ModalPopup control. check the demo: [http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx]. please check the all control demo I'm sure your solution is there.

Comment: No..I need something that will happen after page redirection or on a new page...because I have already done a coding like this so there is no chance to change the entire code

Comment: Please let me clear: in the case People Enrolled = 8 when anyone click on that, a new popup or panel should open with the detail with enrolled user, right? If so, surely you can use ModelPopup control and even you can modify as per your need.

Comment: I don't want any popup control but something like collapsible slider

Comment: ok then. you can pass querystring with certain value in the redirected page and check the value in the pageLoad event and then fire the panel or div accordingly. Even collapsible slider out there in ajaxcontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Henry has already given you the simplest example of toggling divs. To have a complete solution, you have different choices

1. In case, you wish to use your existing page that displays the user information then you can do that by loading a iframe inside the child div.
2. Yet another way to have the information loaded onto current page in child div and only control the visibility.
3. Or on the first click, you can retrieve the content by AJAX and load it into the child dive.

Comment: No..I need something that will happen after page redirection or on a new page...because I have already done a coding like this so there is no chance to change the entire code

Comment: @VishalSuthar, #1 would be least disruptive option as it would be loading you existing popup/details page into the i-frame. However, you still need to change the origin page for loading iframe on click!